# Reading and writing large files in openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to copy cells from a large excel file to another large excel file, both the files are .xlsx. I am using openpyxl module. Below is my code:

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb1=openpyxl.load_workbook('File1.xlsx',read_only=True)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\U6038633\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 118, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Users\U6038633\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1108, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\U6038633\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1175, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('Consolidated GL Line Item report_YTD.xlsx',read_only=True)
  File "C:\Users\U6038633\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 171, in load_workbook
    archive = _validate_archive(filename)
  File "C:\Users\U6038633\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 121, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(f, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Users\U6038633\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1108, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\U6038633\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1175, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

While opening in write mode, I used the code:

```
wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('File2.xlsx',write_only=True)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('Consolidated GL Line Item report_YTD.xlsx',write_only=True)
TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'write_only'
```

Comment: `load_workbook` is not used for saving files. check [this link](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#write-only-mode). Use `Workbook.save()` method. Also all XLSX files are zip files so either the file is corrupt or it is encrypted: AFAIK openpyxl does not support encrypted XLSX files

Answer (score 0):

There is no Parameter `write_only=True`

> [Docs » openpyxl package](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html?highlight=load_workbook)
>
> ```
> load_workbook(filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=False, data_only=False, guess_types=False, keep_links=True)
> ```

Use:

```
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('File2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Perhaps the @GJ14 was conflating loading a workboook with other ways of creating a workbook because there is the possibility of doing [`wb2 = Workbook(write_only=True)`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#write-only-mode) and then after writing sheets and rows to the workbook doing `wb2.save('File2.xlsx')`.  There are some constraints with that approach, but one benefit is a much lower memory overhead and the OP mentions his Excel files are large.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: The OP want _" from a large excel file to another large excel file"_. Your ` wb2 = Workbook(write_only=True)` creats a **new* Workbook.